# filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated showing invalid operation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, request, nunit

I am writting unit tests. I am new to unit test. I have no idea how to test this method. Should i unit test private method? I am using rhino mock.

```
        private bool RedirectToAppraiserProfilePage(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) { return false; }
        IPrincipal principal = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (!principal.IsInRole(RoleEnum.Appraiser.ToString())) { return false; }
        if (!this.GetType().IsDefined(typeof(ForbidDisagreedAppraisers), true)) { return false; }
        AppraiserDTO appraiser = this.employeeService.GetLoggedInAppraiser();
        return !appraiser.AcceptTermsOfAgreement;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I wouldn´t test private methods but it seems you need some general guiding on what unit tests really are and how you should approach the problem.

What you need to ask yourself when writing unit tests:

1. Is the method I am testing stateless? (I.e. not dependent on other methods or modules)
   If yes - possible to write unit test | If no - Is it possible to use dependency injection or mocks/stubs to make method stateless for testing purposes? For instance, in your case I would change the method signature to take the IAuthorizationComponent interface as parameter instead so that you can use dependency injection to test your method by sending your own implementation (filterContext)
2. What does the method do? (I.e. What is the algorithm)
   Specify parameters and their variations and the expected outcome (e.g. return values).
3. Identify the base case (i.e. Where everything goes as expected)
   Write a unit test with these parameters and assert for the expected outcome.
4. Identify alternative cases (e.g. failed logins, wrongful input parameters etc)
   Verify that the method behaves correctly by asserting the outcome.

Comment: I have looked over internet , i am using reflection for testing private, protected methods. It is possible with reflection. But problem is still there.

Comment: Dude, do you have any idea what you are doing? Reflection for testing methods?!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question about testing private methods:

You should test functionality which is imlemented in private methods via calling public methods.

See explanation why:

When tests call **only public methods** then it is easy to do any refactoring within class implementation (extract new private methods, rename them, change parameters of private methods, etc.). And tests will guarantee that everithing still works well.
In that case the tests set is **the specification** for class. It says **what** should be done but don't say **how** it should be done.

When tests call **private methods** then refactoring can't be done so simple. You will need to rewrite tests as well. And of course these tests can't guarantee that code still works after refactoring.
Moreover it is necessary to test public methods anyway and check whether they call private methods correctly. As any well-tested private method is useless if it is not used by public methods.

Regarding question about error with `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated`:

I believe it is besause `filterContext.HttpContext` is not valid in unit test scope. You can find details about mocking `HttpContext` e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422347/issues-mocking-the-mvc-controllercontext-request).